# GEO location leak with mechanicalsoup

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

i am trying to **scrape** some data from eBay.de, using a proxy which is located in Germany. I tried different webpages to double check it.

```
import mechanicalsoup

proxies = {"http": "http://.....",
           "https": "https://...."}

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.session.proxies = proxies
browser.set_user_agent(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36')

browser.open('https://www.ebay.de/sch/internet.shop.world/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from=/de')
browser.launch_browser()
```

if i am trying to use this code without VPN, but with proxy with my ip adress located outside from germany i get here just one article.

If i try the same with VPN with a german vpn server and without proxy, i get here alot more articles. Is there anything which a vpn server let ebay more believe the user is from germany then just a proxy?

the timezone is correct with the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

try using accept-language in your header using your language:

```
headers = {# 'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4',
            'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
          }
browser.set_user_agent(
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36')

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.session.proxies = {}
browser.open('https://www.ebay.de/sch/internet.shop.world/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from=/de',headers=headers)
browser.launch_browser()
```